# Looking for advice on authentication and authorization

Tags: react-native, authentication, redux, expo, authorization

I am building a mobile application with react native + expo. I am using Redux for my client state. React query for server state.

On login using a username and password I fetch access token. I store that token in redux store and use the useSelector() hook to grab token from store and pass it in my API calls. On logout I clear out my store.

I am under the impression that this is a security flaw for my token to be stored unencrypted in the client side code.

My solution is to refactor my application to use Expo Secure Store. Which allows me to store encrypted token in keychain services(ios) and sharedPreferences(android). Where I could retrieve token value using a key and thus removing the actual token from my client side code.

Does this solution make sense? Hoping someone can confirm before I refactor my whole app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must also control this by token expiry. Also, can you also tell in more detail, how you think someone can grab that token to misuse it.

Comment: Could you further explain the token expire or point me towards some relevant documentation. 

Well one way I could think of. Say someone gets a users password and email. 

Well if you have access token and endpoint you could access the users photos through something like postman. Just an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define exp of token in claims

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"ES256","kid":"1"}.{
  "aud": ["https://xyz/"],
  "iss": "https://xyz/authserver/v1",
  "sub": "abc",
  "sys": "abc",
  "exp": 1675943895,
  "iat": 1675943295,
  "jti": "5656757",
  "scp": "example",
  "roles": ["any"],
  "ver": "1.0.0"
}
```